# mongoimport large csv file runtime: VirtualAlloc of 5131534336 bytes failed with errno=1455

Tags: mongodb, csv, bigdata, mongoimport

I am trying to import a large csv file in mongo using mongoimport as follows:

```
mongoimport -d dbname -c collectionName --type csv --file filename -f "a,b" --numInsertionWorkers 9
```

But as soon as it reaches 100%, I get the following error.

```
runtime: VirtualAlloc of 5131534336 bytes failed with errno=1455
fatal error: runtime: cannot map pages in arena address space

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x85cfd4, 0x30)
        C:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x9c
runtime.sysMap(0xc452210000, 0x131dd0000, 0xc0420e6301, 0xa52d18)
        C:/go/src/runtime/mem_windows.go:116 +0x12c
runtime.(*mheap).sysAlloc(0xa39620, 0x131dd0000, 0x0)
        C:/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:407 +0x381
runtime.(*mheap).grow(0xa39620, 0x98ee4, 0x0)
        C:/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:726 +0x69
runtime.(*mheap).allocSpanLocked(0xa39620, 0x98ee4, 0xc04215d000)
        C:/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:630 +0x4f9
runtime.(*mheap).alloc_m(0xa39620, 0x98ee4, 0x100000000, 0x572fd88)
        C:/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:515 +0xee
runtime.(*mheap).alloc.func1()
        C:/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:579 +0x52
runtime.systemstack(0x572fd88)
        C:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:314 +0xb5
runtime.(*mheap).alloc(0xa39620, 0x98ee4, 0x100000000, 0xc0421083b0)
        C:/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:580 +0x7a
runtime.largeAlloc(0x131dc7294, 0x572fe00, 0x4522a1)
        C:/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:774 +0x9a
runtime.mallocgc.func1()
        C:/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:669 +0x45
runtime.systemstack(0xc042016a00)
        C:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:298 +0x7e
runtime.mstart()
        C:/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1079

goroutine 35 [running]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
        C:/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:252 fp=0xc04211bc20 sp=0xc04211bc18
runtime.mallocgc(0x131dc7294, 0x0, 0x1000, 0x0)
        C:/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:670 +0x942 fp=0xc04211bcc0 sp=0xc04211bc20
runtime.rawstring(0x131dc7294, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/go/src/runtime/string.go:289 +0x8c fp=0xc04211bcf8 sp=0xc04211bcc0
runtime.rawstringtmp(0x0, 0x131dc7294, 0xc04211bd80, 0x5c92c4, 0xc0421023c0, 0xc042042040, 0xa0da20)
        C:/go/src/runtime/string.go:111 +0xa8 fp=0xc04211bd38 sp=0xc04211bcf8
runtime.slicebytetostring(0x0, 0xc24a210000, 0x131dc7294, 0x207ffffff, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/go/src/runtime/string.go:93 +0x45 fp=0xc04211bd90 sp=0xc04211bd38
github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/mongoimport/csv.(*Reader).parseRecord(0xc04211e280, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
```

I am not sure about the number of records in the file but the file size is roughly 4.5GB. Is there something I am doing wrong here? Please help! I have followed the following tutorial to start with
https://www.khalidalnajjar.com/insert-200-million-rows-into-mongodb-in-minutes

Comment: It looks like you do not have enough memory. Try not to use `--numInsertionWorkers 9`, it may import longer time, but it should help.

Comment: Is there a memory efficient way to do this?

Comment: It may be... when it does not run in parallel, it needs less memory... did it help?